# SQL Plus view created without errors but I can not call it

Tags: view, sqlplus

I have created a view in SQL Plus as follows.

```
CREATE VIEW jour_cond
AS
SELECT c.nom, c.prenom FROM Conducteur c 
JOIN Affectation a ON c.Id_conducteur = a.Id_conducteur
JOIN Trajet t ON a.ID_Trajet = t.ID_Trajet
WHERE t.date_depart = sysdate;
```

And I have added a value which is the date of today to the column date_depart. But when I call for this view it doesn't show the result. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that 'sysdate' is working just when it is called from dual. So for the last line I should have written ;
'WHERE t.date_depart = (select sysdate from dual)'